# Simple malloc function in c

Tags: c, malloc

```
#define SIZE 7000

static char buf[SIZE]; 
static char *bufptr = buf;

struct node 
{
    int reg_num;
    int val;
    char var_name[30];
    char var_str[100];
    struct node *memroy;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* add(struct node *head, int i)
{
    struct node *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->reg_num = i;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        head->next = add(head->next, i);
    }
    return head;
} 


void* malloc(int n) 
{
    if (buf + SIZE - bufptr >= n) 
    { 
        bufptr += n;
        return bufptr - n;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

When I run my programm it crashes during the assignment `temp->next = NULL`.

I think the problem is in my malloc function. I tested it with `malloc` in libraries and it worked correctly, but I not allowed to use libraries and must write a new `malloc` function.

Comment: I don't want to use sbrk() and brk() I need just a simple malloc just for allocation not free and realloc and...

Comment: Did you try using the debugger to find where it crashes?

Comment: DON't cast the return type of malloc!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Standard warning: [Do not cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1151654)

Comment: Yes.but in returned value from malloc i get crash

Comment: That's a risky and inefficient way to append a node to a list.

Comment: To avoid confusion, always use a distinguishable name for user defined functions. Don't use the same name as the library function itself.

Comment: compiling using gcc with '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'  exposes several problems with the code: 1) conflict with built-in function malloc()  2) 'NULL' not defined  3) control reached end of non-void function without a return statement.

Answer (score 7):

You never check the return of your `malloc` yet you *know* it can `return NULL;`.
Check if `temp` is `NULL` before doing `temp->next = NULL`;

Answer (score -2):

My problem don't has relation with kind of pointer and returned value from 
`malloc()`.I have problem with size of `buf[]` and by 
increment of size my problem solved.Tnx from every one.

Comment: Yeah, but you have to check if `malloc` didn't return NULL, otherwise your program will crash, when it will return NULL. Moreover you shouldn't really name your function `malloc`, as `stdlib` is often used library and you will have symbol clash.

Comment: Please don't comment your question in an answer.